# Duplicate a class method to allow more than one names

Tags: c++, c++20

Say I have a class like

```
struct Demo {
  void read() { /* some implementation */ }
};
```

Is it possible to define a method `get()` that is identical to `read()` without having to re-write the code?

Obviously the usual shortcut would suffice:

```
void get() { return read(); }
```

but I was wondering whether there's a more succinct way, e.g.

```
struct Demo {
  void read() { /* some implementation */ }
  void get() = read();
};
```

I know this is commonplace with `operator[]` and `getX, getY` or `getX` vs `x` etc in vector-like classes but haven't seen any alternative techniques there. In cases were templates and variadic arguments are involved, it becomes cumbersome to forward all arguments just to create an alias essentially.

Comment: No, there is no way to create an alias like you are asking for. Having `get()` **call** `read()` (you don't need the `return` since `read()` returns `void`) is the correct solution.

Comment: Nope, there's no short syntax. You could try to come up with a macro that generates those wrappers for you, but the syntax is going to look ugly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I use the return because it allows me to create a macro `ALIAS` that works both for value returning methods and `void` ones (it is allowed to return a void method). But that macro is hideous and doesn't do much when there are arguments

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've caught some presentation from Herb Sutter on meta classes and have the impression I'd be able to do that. I'm assuming that none of this is affecting the upcoming standards (??)

Comment: @LorahAttkins I remember Herb saying that Meta Classes is an idea for the far future. He is trying to set the path where C++ should go. I don't think it will come too soon.

Comment: Yeah, metaclasses are not in the standard yet.

Comment: The question reminded me of a term "abominable type" :) `using read_fn = void(); read_fn read; read_fn get; `